# Tradingview - pine script - How to config or code alert display will same order in list of trade

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i Has a strategy using request.security.
My problem is alert display different order in list of trade
example :

error 1 : Alert show more than / less than order in list of trade

error 2 : Alert show not same position of Long / short on chart

[Alert show less than order in list of trade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOCba.jpg)

[Alert show more than and not same position of order in list of trade - example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFm5X.jpg)

[Alert show more than and not same position of order in list of trade - example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXl2x.jpg)

[Properties Setting of strategy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH2IZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

request.security can work with alert ambiguously, because it is related with other symbols and taimfreims. For detail answer on your questions, please give me look your script

Comment: here is my script
https://www.mediafire.com/file/7i5wmbsc1udv438/OCC51_v5.txt/file